# Does biasing of address pins require a resistor?

Tags: resistors, i2c, bias, addressing

I'm a total newbie fooling around with a project of mine.

I want to use an MCP23017 I2C port extender ([Data sheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/21952b-70868.pdf)) for my Arduino project.

The chip has three hardware pins that must be externally biased.

I apologize if the question is silly, but, can I just connect the pins to V+ or GND, or do I need to put a resistor in series to limit the current? I looked around a bit but I wasn't able to find an answer.

Comment: Don't forget the reset pin as well as the three address lines, looks like that should be tied high as well.

Comment: yup, good catch :) thanks, and thanks for fixing the link, too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can directly connect these pins to GND or V+.

The reason you did not find this explicitly stated is that it is standard that a high-impedance digital input can be connected directly to a logical 0 or 1. When a resistor was needed this would be stated explicitly.

Using a resistor instead of a hard connection might be convenient when you need to change the address on a finished PCB: you can short the pin to the opposite supply rail without damaging anything.

Comment: _"Using a resistor instead of a hard connection might be convenient..."_   


This is often a zero-ohm link/resistor which doesn't impose significant resistance but is useful for its standard form factor.